# reactjs continuous re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was watching Wes Bos' speech recognition application, and thought of developing that in React.
So I started and everything was going great, I used hooks and context for state management, but then I got stuck so here what is really happening:

So as the user says any color name that is mentioned,  the app strike-through the name of the color (add a css class to that color).

But as soon as another name is called the already striked through color becomes inactive (removes the css class from the previous color name and add the css class to the new one), because that component (ColorList) is getting re-rendered again and again.
I want to persist that strike-through on that individual color name.

**Colors component** (Which renders all the list of colors)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";

import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

import { colors } from "../utils/colors";
import { ColorList } from "./ColorList";

const Colors = () => {
  const [colors1, setColors] = useState([]);

  const colorArray = Object.keys(colors).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  useEffect(() => {
    setColors(colorArray);
  }, []);
  const { color, already } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // console.log("context", context.color);

  return (
    <div className="colors" style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>
      {colors1.map((colors, index) => (
        <ColorList key={index} colors={colors} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Colors;
```

**Color List Component**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { isDark } from "../utils/colors";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

export const ColorList = props => {
  const { color} = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <span
      className={`color ${isDark(props.colors) && "dark"} ${props.colors} ${
        props.colors === color ? "got" : ""
      }`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: `${props.colors}` }}
    >
      {props.colors}
    </span>
  );
};
```

GlobalState Context

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

import AppReducer from "./AppReducer";

const initialState = {
  colorName: "",
  alreadyDone: []
};

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalState = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  function changeColorName(color) {
    dispatch({
      type: "CHANGE",
      payload: color
    });
  }

  function addToAlready(color) {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADDTO",
      payload: color
    });
  }

  console.log("from Context", state);
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        color: state.colorName,
        changeColor: changeColorName,
        alreadyDone: state.alreadyDone,
        already: addToAlready
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you please post `isDark` util and the `GlobalContext`? Please add more of your code. I can't see what's causing the re-render loop. `UseEffect` is not needed in `Colors` component but this is not causing the loop - you could add it directly to `useState(colorArray)`.

Comment: Where do you store the selected colors? I would add it to a top-level container or context as `selectedColors` array and use it during ColorList rendering with a prop. See the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-star-q5swz) to get an idea.

Comment: When i say a color it renders the component, the new said color is added to the global state, and it is getting changed every time which i think is right.

Comment: I've added a color adding feature to the linked sandbox (with-out context). I'll check your context code later. Can you please add the code that is using `GlobalState` component?